# Astable multivibrator GaN MOS

Tags: mosfet, design, multivibrator, astable

I'm a beginner in electronics design. I'm trying to build on LTSpice an astable multivibrator using the GaN transistors GS-065-030-2-L 650 V E-mode. The idea is to obtain an oscillating output of 24 V, i.e. the supply level, with a frequency of 1 Hz.

I have found on the web many references to the circuit design via BJT, but not with MOSFET. Can someone explain to me the differences and the theory necessary to model the resistances and the capacitances in the circuit?

In this image the circuit design and simulation is shown. After the first oscillation, the circuit stops working as expected.

[image: The circuit design and simulation - after the first oscillation, the circuit stops working as expected]